# Animation not working on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation

I made a zoom-effect on a background of a div.
All worked till today when it stopped functioning for Chrome. For every other browser it works perfectly.

here is my code:

```css
.project_image {
    width: 582px;
    height: 280px;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
    -o-transition: all .2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all .2s linear;
    transition: all .2s linear;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.project_image:hover {
 background-size: 110%;
}
```

On Chrome, when i hover the div, the background-size is set instantly to 110%, not slowly as wanted.

edit: fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ca79cohz/

Comment: Create a working jsfiddle of your codes, this isn't working.

Comment: the css works fine for me, I tested in chrome, IE and firefox... all the same

Comment: i updated the post with a fiddle, for me is not working, chrome  51.0.2704.84 m

Comment: Here is the working edited JS fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ca79cohz/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this changes,

```
.project_image {
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.project_image:hover {
background-size: 110% 110%;
}
```